# factors levels and zero variances

Tags: r, naivebayes

I'm encountering this error when running Naive Bayes with klaR package.

I want to share data in order to replicate but I have some constraints on doing so and since I'm unsure of what's going on am unable to create a dataset that will recreate myself. I'm hoping someone who reads this may have encountered and overcome this error before.

Here is the error:

```
Error in if (any(temp)) stop("Zero variances for at least one class in variables: ",  : 
      missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed
```

I found some posts online on this already:
[here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/192884/naive-bayes-error-with-caret) and [here](https://stat.ethz.ch/pipermail/r-help/2007-June/133488.html)

From what I can gather I have some levels that have 1 or zero instances within my data.

The trouble is I cannot find any. I tried this:

```
sapply(df, function(x) table(x))
```

to see if any returned tables showed an instance of zero or one but with nearly 400 dummy variables I cannot see any - all have at least several instances of 0 or 1 factor levels that I can see.

Is it possible to tell R to highlight which levels are causing the problem? I'm not sure of my next course of action since I cannot find any levels that might be culprits.

Comment: Zero variance also mean, you can have the same number but multiple times?! Does this help?

Comment: Is that error coming from your code or the function code? In either case, `which(is.na(temp))` may help you find the problem.

Comment: @sebastian-c it's coming from the function code so not sure how to access variable temp. It comes from this step model <- NaiveBayes(target ~., data=dataplay) based on KlaR package of Niave Bayes

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in the condition being tested, you can reproduce the error with:

```
if (NA) {
    print("ERROR")
}
```

You could correct it to `anyNA(temp)` or `any(is.na(temp))`.

If the error is really on the variance message you could test it with `sapply(df, function(x){length(table(x)) == 1}`.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Actually, variable temp is a mystery variable from within the package, I never created it myself. I tried sapply(df, function(x){length(table(x)) == 1} as you suggested which returned a list of TRUE or FALSE. I then did a table on this list (called ind) (grepl("TRUE", ind)) and all values where FALSE. So it looks like all my levels have more than one value, so just not sure why r is throwing this error

Comment: Whatever you do with your data won't solve the problem, the test will be performed regardless the variation of your data. Try to raise the issue to the package maintainer, or if it is open and available to correct yourself the mistake.